# trouble using group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data as follows

```
A        |  B      | C            |   D          |   E     |  F
217731   |  24856  | 01/01/2006   | 03/31/2007   |  0569   | 972450
217731   |  24856  | 04/01/2007   | 09/30/2008   |  0569   | 972450
217731   |  24856  | 10/01/2008   | 12/31/2008   |  0569   | 972450
217731   |  24856  | 01/01/2009   | 12/31/2009   |  0569   | 972450

217731   |  24856  | 01/01/2010   | 09/30/2011   |  0569   | 318704
217731   |  24856  | 10/01/2011   | 03/04/2012   |  0569   | 318704

217731   |  24856  | 03/05/2012   | 09/30/2012   |  0569   | 972450
217731   |  24856  | 10/01/2012   | 07/31/2013   |  0569   | 972450
```

And i need output as

```
 A     |  B     |  C          | D           | F
217731 | 24856  |  01/01/2006 | 31/12/2009  | 972450
217731 | 24856  |  01/01/2010 | 04/03/2012  | 318704
217731 | 24856  |  05/03/2012 | 31/07/2013  | 972450
```

when i use  group by clause i get output as follows

```
 A      |  B      | C          | D          | F
217731  | 24856   | 01/01/2006 | 07/31/2013 | 972450
217731  | 24856   | 01/01/2010 | 03/04/2012 | 318704
```

Comment: Post your queries, please.

Comment: The point being that groups 1 and 3 have the same E value but are separated by the other E value? Or some logic based on continuity of dates? Or something else? I'm guessing this is `select A, B, min(C), max(D), E from Table group by A, B, E`.

Comment: Is he formatting the date too?

Comment: There's some inconsistency in your sample input and output - the dates are mm/dd/yyyy in the input and dd/mm/yyyy in the output. That's not fatal but it's definitely confusing. Additionally, the first row of your expected output has a date that's not in the input (`01/01/2006`). Just a guess: do you need the lowest value of `C` and the highest value of `D` grouped by `A`, `B`, and `F`? Also, the next time you edit the question could you please fix the spello of "clause" in the title? The titles are important for future users who are searching for help.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to identify different periods of time that have the same keys.  Fortunately, Oracle has a wealth of analytic functions for this, because a simple `group by` is not sufficient.

Here is the logic that the below query uses.  The innermost subquery creates a flag (`StartPeriod`) based on the dates and key columns in the row.  This identifies when a new period begins, because column C is not 1 day larger than the previous column D.

Then, the `StartPeriod` is accumulated as a cumulative sum.  This assigns the same value to all groups in the same period.  At this point, there is enough information for using `group by`.  You need to include the additional `grping` column.

```
select A, B, MIN(C) as C, MAX(D) as D, E, F
from (select t.*, SUM(StartPeriod) over (partition by A, B, E, F order by C) as grping
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when lag(D) over (partition by A, B, E, F order by C) = C - 1
                         then 0
                         else 1
                    end) as StartPeriod
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by A, B, E, F, grping
```

Comment: Hi Team, It's working fine with the above query but if the days gap between two time periods is more than one than also the obove query will work fine???

Comment: @user2614856 . . . Not as written.  You can change the `= C - 1` to put in a threshold, such as `>= C - 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Also try to use this query if your table isn't big:

```
select A,B,min(C),max(D),F
from
(
select t2.*,
(select count(A) from t where 
  (t.A<>t2.A or t.B<>t2.B or t.F<>t2.F) 
   and t.c<t2.c) Group_n
from t t2
 ) t3
group by A,B,F,Group_n
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11f9d/8)